# Edquota editing user settings via PHP

Tags: php, centos, ssh

I'm trying to automate the process for my ftp user creation, however I need to be able to set the quota of a user via PHP, in a shell on a remote server, using SSH. I would use `edquota username` however is there a way to do this via PHP?

Here is console preview

```
[root@s1 home]# edquota user2

Disk quotas for user user2 (uid 509):
  Filesystem                   blocks       soft       hard     inodes     soft     hard
  /dev/simfs                     2820          0       4096          6        0     4096
~                                                                                                                                                        
~
```

Now what i'd have to do is edit the amount of blocks, but how would I do this over ssh2_exec() ?

Comment: SSH and FTP are networking protocols, how do you want to configure a quota with them?

Comment: its configuring disk quota for a system user(ftp user)

Comment: You mean using a shell?

Comment: Well i'd have to run edquota username then edit this with editor.. however I need to do this via SSH over PHP

Comment: Do you need to connect to a remote server or not?

Comment: ? I'm not sure where we are misunderstanding each other. What I need to do is use a php script to edit a user's quota as you would in shell

Comment: php allows use of functions such as shell2 for shell commands but i'm not sure how I would go about doing that as it's not just executing a command

Comment: Yes but you said you needed SSH, which is a networking protocol to connect to a remote server, **not** a shell. So is this php script running on the same host where you want to edit things?

Comment: it shouldn't matter if it's running on same server or not(which it won't be) I can do the connecting, however what I can't figure out how to run the command to achieve the outcome I want(performing edquota <username> and setting the quota)

Comment: It actually does matter, because you can then just use exec() in php. Anyhow I'll add an answer.

Comment: either exec() or ssh2_exec() will behave same as long as you have the permission to execute the command, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the exec method in php and use [setquota](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/storwize/unified_ic/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.storwize.v7000.unified.doc/manpages/setquota.html) instead of edquota:

```
exec("ssh yourserver.com 'setquota -u  username  2820  0 4096  6  0 -a /dev/simfs'");
```

Comment: Completely misunderstood my question. If you execute <edquote username> in console, it will open editor to change the quota and other settings, now where I would get stuck is actually making the change as it's not a file I can download locally, edit it via PHP and then upload back(or not as far as I know) I will update the post a little

Comment: Now I know what you want :)

Comment: :D Sorry, been working for too many hours and it's 6.32am..

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Seems to update 'soft' but not blocks? and I did change the '2820' I tried to add another zero after, didn't help either

Comment: oh hang on the blocks is the current usage, dont worry I will wort it out, thanks so much!